# Spring Security with SAML Token for REST Service

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, saml-2.0

I'm looking for a simple example of a spring security configuration (Java config preferred) on how I can secure my REST Services with Spring-Security and SAML.

There's an Web Application Firewall in front which will only pass requests which contain a valid SAML Token or otherwise redirects to IDP to get one. So I don't have to look if the user is logged in or redirect the user if not so to the IDP.

The only thing I'll need to do is allow only authenticated requests to all REST Services, read the user from SAML-Token and check that the Token is from Airlock.

Later I'll need to add ACL support for more fine granular rights of the user on specific services but I'm already lost with the first part of the integration work in spring security. Any help would be welcome :)

Comment: http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/

Comment: well this link is not new to me but the samle contains a fully featured SAML Security configuration with redirects to IDP and login mask. What I want is to have one which only checks for SAML Token and adds the principal to the security context, more a SAMLFilter than this...

Comment: the magic happens here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/saml/SAMLProcessingFilter.java is this what you mean ?

Comment: maybe this will be the part I need in the end. but actually I'm having another problem until I reach that goal:
I've installed twice the SAML Sample Application, one running under port 8080, the other under 9000. When I login on Application 1 and get there the SAML Token from ssocircle.com and go then to Application 2 the logger tells me:
o.s.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger  : AuthNRequest;SUCCESS;0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1;com:vdenotaris:spring:sp;http://idp.ssocircle.com;;;
but I get redirect to ssocircle with this message displayed:
Reason: Unable to do Single Sign On or Federation. any hint?

Comment: I just recognized that the same thing happens if i try to get a new token from application 2 (port 9000). is there any configuration which prevents the samle application to run on a different port than 8080? (I used the java based config from [link](https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample)

Comment: well, this is a different question... post it seperately...

Comment: ok, have fixed the last issue, was based on metadata not uploaded to ssocirlce. will now go on with minimizing the samle app so that application 2 only filters if the token from app1 is valid and trusted.

Comment: Hi, any progress on this? I need exactly the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the magic happens here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/saml/SAMLProcessingFilter.java

in `attemptAuthentication()`, it gets the SAML message, parse it and gets the token (`SAMLAuthenticationToken`). Then it tries to authenticate the user: `authenticate(token);`

Comment: Can we use this to validate the rest endpoint? If yes, can you please share the code base (if you have)?